# Linux Printer - retry job on another printer

Tags: printing, cups, printer, lp

Suppose a printer is disconnected either by power failure or by network failure,

When I give it this command `lp -d printername my_file.txt` the print job would be on hold, so `lpstat -W "not-completed"` command would show me something like this:

```
printername-146633            myuser           39936   fri 09 oct 2020 12:29:08 -03
```

In this case, `146633` is the job id. What I want is to tell `anotherprinter` to come for the rescue. In this case, what would be the command?

I was imagining something like `lp --job-id 14633 --redirect-to anotherprinter`. Is there any command that would do basically this?

Comment: Yes, there is `lpmove`.

Comment: Thank you so much!